# Linux-like top/netstat/etc. on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, macports

Unix utilities on Mac OS X are quite painful to use. `port install coreutils +with_default_names` and a few other such replacements fix most of them, but it leaves some in broken Mac OS X defaults - most annoyingly `top` and `netstat`, but I'm sure I could think of a few more.

I'm guessing that commands like `top` and `netstat` are quite OS specific, so just grabbing sources of their Linux equivalents and recompiling won't work.

What's the best equivalent of these and other such commands that works on Mac OS X?

Comment: Calling them "replacements" may not be historically accurate. They are derived from the BSD variants, and historically many of those predate the linux tools that you are used to. Good questions though, and similar issues exist for those of us who use fink instead of ports.

Comment: Your question would be better if it contained less editorializing. Crossing over from one Unix-like OS to another always brings surprises in the way different common Unix commands have followed different evolutionary paths on different platforms. I've used  Solaris, DEC Ultrix, AT&T SysV, HP-UX, GNU/Linux (many distros), NEXTSTEP, OpenStep, BSDI, Xenix/SCO, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Mac OS X, and CygWin. If you let yourself get too accustomed to unique features of one flavor's tools, it's painful when you go to another favor. That doesn't make them "broken".

Comment: Right, and don't forget Hurd. Other than Linux and OSX, the rest of your list is of historical interest only.

Comment: @taw: Solaris is still in use in a lot of places, particularly for zfs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Many netstat features can be replaced with a *lsof* command. I was often using

```
netstat -lnp | grep 1234
```

to find out who was listening on port 1234. With lsof (that is available on both systems), I can do:

```
lsof -i :1234
```

The top command on OSX is not bad either, it's just different. And I'm quite sure some of the metrics only make sense on Mac.

Note that `lsof -Pi :1234` should make it a bit faster by not trying to resolve the service names (of the ports).

Comment: OSX `lsof` is better better `netstat` than OSX `netstat`, thanks.

Comment: add `-P` to prevent name resolution and make it way faster. So linux `netstat -ntlp` kinda like `lsof -Pi | grep -i listen`. Still don't know how multiple PID's could listen on the same port, not something I see in linux :/

Comment: @RayFoss On Mac and some other OS, a process can listen on *.*:1234 and another one on 127.0.0.1:1234. The latter having the precedence. That's forbidden on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Oh cool, `htop` is in Homebrew! I guess it isn't a clone of Linux `top` but if you decide to use `htop` on Linux then I guess `htop` on OS X won't be too far off.

Comment: its not a direct replacement as you cant get a quick list of listening servers